# Animate the getting of a random number

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'd like to animate the 'getting' of a random number with a bit of theatre. I'd like the following to happen when the user clicks the number:

1. The number fades to a different colour (e.g. 2 second duration)
2. Once the above is complete, the number then flicks through several different random numbers - this should look smooth and animated
3. The final random number is displayed
4. The number then fades back to the original colour

I've read lots of answers on here and come up with something similar to what I'd like with the following...

```
func numberClicked() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(2,
        animations: {
            self.numberLabel.textColor = uicolor_verylight
            self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        },
        completion: {(value: Bool) in
            for i in 1...30 {
                dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64((Double(i)/20) * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.numberLabel.fadeTransition(0.2)
                    self.numberLabel.text = String(Int(arc4random_uniform(30) + 1))
                    if(i == 30) {
                        UIView.animateWithDuration(2, animations: { () -> Void in
                            self.numberLabel.textColor = uicolor_normal
                            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                        })
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

This uses this UIView extension...

```
extension UIView {
    func fadeTransition(duration:CFTimeInterval) {
        let animation:CATransition = CATransition()
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:
            kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        animation.type = kCATransitionFade
        animation.duration = duration
        self.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: kCATransitionFade)
    }
}
```

The problem is that my animateWithDurations aren't animating, and the loop runs immediately, not after the first animation happened.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Or perhaps there is a simpler way to accomplish what I'm doing here? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried to check if `value` is true? also for better style remove the `{value: Bool}` and just put `completed in`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textColor property of the UILabel is not animatable. The main reason its not animatable because UILabel uses a CALayer instead of CATextLayer.

One of the solution can be subclassing the UILabel and make it use a CATextLayer. This is pretty cumbersome to some extent as CATextLayer doesn't have support for NSAttributedText.

One workaround that I found out is instead of using animateWithDuration you can use transitionWithView and use TransitionCrossDissolve as an option. It will give you a nice fade effect for your text colour transition.
Look at the following code for eg.

```
UIView.transitionWithView(view, duration: 2.0, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: { () -> Void in
    //animation code
    }, completion: nil)
```

Using the above as reference below is your code.

```
 UIView.transitionWithView(self.numberLabel, duration: 2.0, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.numberLabel.backgroundColor = uicolor_verylight
            self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
            }) { (value: Bool) -> Void in
                if value == true {
                    for i in 1...30 {
                        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64((Double(i)/20) * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            self.numberLabel.text = String(Int(arc4random_uniform(30) + 1))
                            if(i == 30) {
                                UIView.transitionWithView(self.numberLabel, duration: 2.0, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: { () -> Void in
                                    self.numberLabel.textColor = uicolor_normal
                                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                                    }, completion: nil)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
```

Hope this will solve your problem.